# PC freezing, mouse constantly disconnecting, constant USB disconnection noise

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, freeze

My friend's PC has been constantly freezing. When it freezes, his mouse disconnects, but all the other USB ports are still active. Before his PC freezes, there is a constant USB disconnection noise, even if the mouse is not plugged in. When he restarts his PC, his motherboard says that something might be corrupted, and the PC does not always boot up to the login screen. He has tried to switch his mouse and switch the USB port, but nothing is working. What could be the problem, and how can he fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Download and run the Manufacturer's Diagnostic App and look for errors.

Find (Internet Search) memtest86.exe and make a bootable USB Key (Rufus).  Start with this key and check memory (memory error can cause the above.

Once started look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Reliability History.  What stopped working errors are there that coincide withe the crash. Post a screen shot in your question

Look in that computer's %SystemRoot%\Minidump folder and see if there are any minidump files. Post them in your question and start the review with Nirsoft Blue Screen View.

Start with the above, do some testing, and then let us know.